# Organization chart using Active Directory

Tags: windows, charts

Is there any tool which can depict Organization chart using data pulled from Active Directory.

I am looking for portable thick client which can run on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the [Org Chart PowerPack](http://powergui.org/entry.jspa?externalID=2424&categoryID=21). I haven't implemented this myself but it looks promising and seems easy enough to put into play.

Here are some [instructional videos](http://powergui.org/shares/powergui/sbin/docs/Org_Chart_PowerPack/Org_Chart_PowerPack.html).

I'm not sure if this fulfills the portable requirement though.

Comment: Link is broken. PowerGUI has been swallowed up in corporate acquisitions. In 2015 it was still available in [a few places](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2015/01/30/download-links-for-powergui-and-qad-cmdlets/) but might be gone completely now. Bottom line: this Q needs a new answer!